# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion

We need to lay out what's on topic and what's off topic.

If you know something is likely to be partially on topic go ahead and list it here as being off-topic. Let's get the structure well laid out.

Comment: are you staff on that site, when you're telling "what should our"

Comment: @genesis - No, jcolebrand is a user, just like you.   Feel free to call this site yours!  (He happens to be a [community moderator on DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/171/jcolebrand), but that doesn't mean much here except that he has experience with the operation of a site. )

Comment: @genesis As far as I know, all sites on SE network are shaped by theirs community

Comment: It _only_ means that I've recently done the growing pains on another site, so know the things to ask _today_ ;)

Comment: This question should always be displayed at the top of the meta question list, until the structure has been laid out. (It's probably more important than the artwork, tagline, etc.)

Comment: @rwong - Then flag it to get the "Featured" tag.  Personally, I think our question list is short enough that we don't need to feature this, but that's debatable.